# Name of the hash algorithms and create an unhash function

Tags: hash

Below is a function to hash a string into a number. I'm curious what would be the name of the below hash function and what would be best approach to create an `unhash` function to turn the number into a string (ex. `61752` to `abc`)?

```
function hash(str){
    const letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    let h = 9

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        let v = letters.indexOf(str[i])
        h = h * 19 + v
    }

    return h
}

console.log(hash("abc")) // will return 61752
```

Comment: What is your goal in this question? The function might be a "hash" in the broadest sense, like they can be used in hash trees, Bloom filters, etc.. But it is not a cryptographic hash in any way.

Comment: You can name it what you want. I suggest to close the question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not about a cryptographically secure hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT - Per the helpful comments, this question involves a sort of broken base19 conversion with redundant characters from t through z.  As such the below does not reverse for any letters after 's'.  It could be fixed but I presume the question is just an intellectual exercise of some kind anyway.  It obviously is NOT a hash, nor is it an efficient coding system, snugly fitting 8 characters in a less than handy 34 bits.

From my rather layman point-of-view, it was difficult to initially spot as a base19 conversion due to the fact it's backwards (we treat the initial string as base19) and because of the way it multiplies 19 in a loop rather than explicitly $19^i$ (yeah I know...).

---

To reverse up to 's':

$61752 \mod 19 = 2$

We then take the rounded down result of 61752/19

Were left with $3250 \mod 19 = 1$

We then take the rounded down result of 3250/19

Were left with $171 \mod 19 = 0$

Here it is in Javascript

```
function rehash(str){
const letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";var out="";

while (str>9) {
  out = letters.charAt(str%19) + out;
  str=Math.floor(str/19)
}
return out}
```

Comment: It's not a hash function. It's base19 :).

Comment: The code fails for some string like "z". But this isn't because of your idea, but the idea in the question isn't injective. A base 19 encoding can't really handle an alphabet with 26 characters.

Comment: Yeah I read @DannyNiu's comment about 15 mins ago and noticed that.  I'll edit the answer.